# Apply different functions to multiple layer xml data using Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, xml, java-8, java-stream

I am currently working with a multi-layer xml data, and I want to apply different functions to different nodes on different layers.

Currently I can save the different layer node values:

```
List<Integer> transactionsGroomIds = 
    transactions.parallelStream()
                .map(node -> node.children().findChildWithName("GROOM"))
                .filter(t -> t.getType() == Transaction.GROCERY)
                .sorted(comparing(Transaction::getValue).reversed())
                .map(Transaction::getId)
                .collect(toList()); 

List<Integer> transactionsCupIds = 
    transactions.parallelStream()
                .map(node -> node.children().findChildWithName("ACCESS"))
                .map(node -> node.children().findChildWithName("CUP"))
                .filter(t -> t.getType() == Transaction.GROCERY)
                .sorted(comparing(Transaction::getValue).reversed())
                .map(Transaction::getId)
                .collect(toList());
```

As you can see, the first list is created by going one layer deep, whereas the second list is created by going two layers deep.

Is there a way to make a combined list?  For example, if I create a Transaction object that has two fields (transactionsGroomIds and transactionsCupIds), is there a way to create a `List<Transaction>` that is able to store both transactionsGroomIds and transactionsCupIds in one stream?

Further clarification:

I want to insert both ids into a Transaction object through constructor. Is there a way in the stream to insert the code:

```
Transaction newTransaction = new Transaction(transactionsGroomIds, transactionsCupIds)
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear if you want to create one single `Transaction` object from those two lists of ids, or if you want to somehow create a list of `Transaction` objects, in which case it's not clear at all which ids from both lists would correspond to each fresh new `Transaction` object. Maybe is it that you need one groom id and one cup id to create a `Transacion` object? Please clarify.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for Guava's [`Streams.zip()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#zip-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.function.BiFunction-).

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Sorry for the confusion, but yes I am trying to get one groom id and one cup id to create a Transaction object.

Comment: @shmosel Thanks for the solution! This is pretty similar to what I have in mind, but is there a Streams.zip() that is getting the longer of the two streams and simply insert null, rather than getting the shorter of the two?

Comment: What makes the decision that two arbitrarily chosen Groom and Cup entities belong together?

Comment: @Holger The logic is similar to that of Streams.zip() where two different streams are being matched, but is there another one that is getting the longer of the two streams and simply insert null for non existent record at the end, rather than going with the shorter of the two in length?

Comment: There is no `Streams.zip`. But anyway, you described a technical behavior, but not the actual logic, i.e. semantic behind it. Why are two entirely unrelated items supposed to be paired? If there was a logical connection, it should show up in the source data already, e.g. these would be either, already be combined within the XML structure or connected via a common ID or attribute that determines the relationship. Being the n’th element of two different streams doesn’t sound like meaningful relationship.

Answer (score 1):

[`Stream.concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-) will take two streams and concatenate them.  You can then do with the combined stream as you please.

Comment: Thanks. But in my case, I want to insert both ids into a Transaction object through constructor.  Is there a way in the stream to insert the code: Transaction newTransaction = new Transaction(transactionsGroomIds, transactionsCupIds)   ?

Comment: Given those two things are the output of the stream, I'm going to say no.